# How to get responseheader location by jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]

how to get response header location with jquery ajax "get"?

here my example code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.url.com',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) { },
    error: function(jqXHR) { }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to access a non simple header (see http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ for more details about simple headers) the server must include the header name you want to access in "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" CORS header.

So, besides "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" headers the server on which you make the call must include:

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location

I tested this on Windows 7 (Chrome 23, Safari 5.1.7, Firefox 17 and Opera 12.11). It seems that only Chrome and Opera are able to access the Location header via getResponseHeader('Location') method, and this only if Access-Control-Expose-Headers header is included in the server response

Comment: This answer got me pointed in the right direction towards getting it working using Amazon's S3 service: in your Bucket's CORS configuration, add `<ExposeHeader>Location</ExposeHeader>` in each of your CORS configuration rules. Here's the [help doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#cors-expose-headers) regarding how to do this in S3

Answer (score 3):

You can can receive a jqXhr object in success callback too which have a `.getResponseHeader()` method which you can use like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://www.url.com',
   data: {},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(res,status,XHR) { 
       var location = XHR..getResponseHeader('Location');
   },
   error: function(jqXHR) { }
});
```

Read more here [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), Search the page for `.getResponseHeader` string.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/yExUe/)

Or try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/yExUe/1/) to check all `response headers`.